# When you extend an abstract class which implements an interface, is it good to also mention this in the child class?

Tags: java, implements

When you extend an **abstract class** which implements an **interface**, does the **child class** change it's behavior if you write that it also implements the same **interface** that the **abstract class** does? Or is it just a readability question if you do it or not?

**Interface** example:

```
public interface Car
{
    public String startEngine();
}
```

**Abstract class** example:

```
public abstract class AbstractCar implements Car
{
    protected String engineStartUpSound;
}
```

**Child class** example #1:

```
public class Volvo extends AbstractCar <---- here
{
    public Volvo()
    { engineStartUpSound = "vroom!"; }

    @Override
    public final String startEngine()
    { return super.engineStartUpSound; }
}
```

**Child class** example #2:

```
public class Volvo extends AbstractCar implements Car <---- here
{
    public Volvo()
    { engineStartUpSound = "vroom!"; }

    @Override
    public final String startEngine()
    { return super.engineStartUpSound; }
}
```

Comment: It makes no difference. `Volvo` already implements `Car` whether it declares it or not.

Comment: Okey, which one of them would you suggest to use?

Comment: Imagine `AbstractCar` would also implement `Driveable, Washable, Parkable, HoldsPassengers` and so on. Which version would you rather use then? ;)